# Error creating an Excel 2013 Template in MVS 2015

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, vsto

I am currently trying to create an add-in template for excel 2013 using Visual Studio in Visual C#. Whenever I try to create a new project I get the following error message:

Cannot open project. The Excel workbook "test.xltx" is missing or corrupted.

I noticed that in the directory for this project there's a .sln file but the .xltx file is missing (just as the error says).

Any clue on how I can fix this?

Here are links to the screenshots of the error that occurs.

[Error Message that pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSwfL.png)

Here are links to the screenshots of the error that occurs.

Thanks

Comment: Not a clue without some code. I can not imagine why the "project" will not open because an excel file is missing. You are going to have to show some code, otherwise answers will be pure speculation. You should view the following…[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry this is my first time posting, I don't have any code since I'm just trying to create a new project. I've added a screenshot of the error but when I create a new project it tries to create a .xltx file, but after I make the project the .xltx file doesn't show up in the project directory so MVS can't find it.

Comment: I am not sure why your project is not opening. I would simply create a new one. A project should not depend on an Excel file to open, so I am curious why you would get this error. Create a new WinForm or Console application. Then look up how to open/create Excel files. There are several ways to do this, but since it appears you already have Office installed on your machine Interop is the option I use. However others may feel that other 3rd party libraries are easier to use. Again this is a preference. In your case look up C# Interop to create Excel files. Try it, and post if you have problems.

Comment: I am guessing that you may be providing improper information when you are creating the project. Can you show a screen shot of what values you are supplying in the create project popup window.

Comment: I have looked up and tried the C# Interop and the code I used works to open an excel work files through visual studio in a console application but I'm not exactly sure what that tells us. This is a screenshot of the project popup window http://prntscr.com/dhg5y8. This is the next window after I name the directory http://prntscr.com/dhg6fo.

Comment: You are using VSTO, in your pictures. I would add a VSTO tag to your question. VSTO is ued to create VSTO **Add-ins** for Office by using Visual Studio. I will not be able help here to create an add-in for Office. I misunderstood your question as one to simply create/open an Excel file.

Comment: Okay I will add the tag, thanks so much !

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problem a couple of weeks ago.

I managed to solve the problem by reinstalling the whole office suite, then preventing Windows/Microsoft Update from installing Excel patches that were released after Oct 2016, although I never really tracked down what exact update caused the problem and for what reason.

Comment: Did you use office 2016 or 2013? I will try that right now

Comment: I use 2013 version.

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3117015/excel-designer-cannot-be-activated-visual-studio)